# Should I explain the reason why I am still taking basic computer science courses when applying for graduate school?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, computer-science, statement-of-purpose

I am an undergraduate student double majoring in computer science in my last year of college, but I am still studying data structure, operation system and will study algorithm and computer architecture in the next semester due to conflict of classes. Should I mention that in my Statement of Purpose for graduate school application?

This is what I have right now:
"Recently, I am studying Data Structure and Operation System and will study Algorithm and Computer Organization next semester due to the conflict of classes of two majors. I am confident that I will excel in these courses because I have gained solid background knowledge in the past few years."

I am not sure if this is worth saying. I have written this because I have heard that applicants have to submit the score of these basic subjects, and I want to explain the reasons why they can not see those grades on my transcript. I am applying for my graduate study of CS in the US. Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: I assume data structures is normally a first- or second-year class. What about the classes that are normally taken during the third or fourth years? Have you already taken those, so you are just out of order? Or are you not going to take those?

Comment: Your assumption is right. What I have studied are program design 1 and 2, computer network, linear algebra, discrete math, compiler and a few elective subjects. I have already taken data structure in my in my first major. Taking it now is just for my second degree. Compiler and one of the elective subjects are normally taken during the last two years. The rest are normally in the first two.